# Schema.org for TV show character page

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

I'm doing Schema.org for a character page for a TV show, and I'm having difficulty figuring out proper types.

This is what I have so far:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "TVSeries",
  "name": "Show Name",
  "url": "URL of Character Page",
  "actor": {
                  "@type": "PerformanceRole",
                  "characterName": "Name of Character",
                  "image": {
                          "@type": "ImageObject",
                          "contentURL": "URL of Image"
                  }
          } 
  }
```

This is obviously just a template for developers to use, but I'm not sure if using type `PerformanceRole` under `actor` is the way to go. If it helps, the page is for the character, and includes a bio about the actor.

Comment: Why do you want to use schema.  I'm not aware of anybody that uses this type of schema.

Comment: Because my boss told me to.

Comment: I'd push back.  I think your boss is wasting your time

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: If someone wants to make use of the data, they will make themselves familiar with the used vocabulary/ontology (or they will use a suitable ontology mapping) -- but given its popularity, it’s likely that they know the Schema.org terms relevant to their use case anyway. [Linked (Open) Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_data) is like an API, but with the huge benefit that consumers don’t have to learn each site’s/service’s different proprietary API (or even fall back to scraping) -- they can simply parse the RDF.

Comment: Are there browser extensions that will make that data useful or something?   I can't find any.  I've never seen any practical benefit to users from having schema data in your pages.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: There are several browser extensions, but I’d say they are primarily used to easily see if the current page has some structured data (example: [OSDS](http://osds.openlinksw.com/)), and to browse it, not to actually (re)use the data -- the webbrowser is typically not the right tool for this job. The classical workflow is to extract the RDF, put it in a triple store, and use SPARQL to query/transform it (or skip the first two steps und use the site’s SPARQL endpoint, if it offers one; [like Wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/), for example).

Answer (score 2):

The `PerformanceRole` item also gets an `actor` property, so that you can provide an item for the `Person` that plays the character.

```json
"actor": {
  "@type": "PerformanceRole",
  "characterName": "William Sherlock Scott Holmes",
  "actor": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Benedict Cumberbatch",
    "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Benedict_Cumberbatch"
  }
}
```

You can read more about how the `Role` types work in the [announcement blog post](http://blog.schema.org/2014/06/introducing-role.html).

For a page that is about a single character (instead of the show itself, or the list of all characters), it could be useful to convey this by using the [`mainEntityOfPage`](https://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) property on the `PerformanceRole`:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "TVSeries",
  "name": "Sherlock",
  "url": "/series/sherlock",

  "actor": {
    "@type": "PerformanceRole",
    "characterName": "William Sherlock Scott Holmes",
    "actor": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "Benedict Cumberbatch",
      "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Benedict_Cumberbatch"
    },
    "mainEntityOfPage": {
      "@type": "ItemPage",
      "url": "/series/sherlock/characters/sherlock-holmes"
    }
  }

}
```

(where `/series/sherlock/characters/sherlock-holmes` is the canonical URL of the current page)

Comment: Is there a reason why we wouldn't just use `Person` as the primary type and have the info trickle down from there? I think I'm just getting confused about why, when, and how to use `mainEntityOfPage` and `mainEntity`.

Comment: @BAM: The top-level item (`TVSeries` in my snippet) does not necessarily represent the primary item (`PerformanceRole` in my snippet). With the `mainEntity` property (or its inverse, `mainEntityOfPage`) you can denote the primary item for a webpage. -- If your page is primarily about a character (instead of its actor), then I think `PerformanceRole` should be the primary item. You could probably model the JSON-LD in such a way that this item (or the `Person`) would also be the top-level item, but this wouldn’t change the semantics.

Comment: Thanks for assistance. I went through and found some of your old posts that discuss `mainEntity` and `mainEntityOfPage` and it definitely cleared some things up for me. Just so I'm clear, though: Is there a reason why you don't just do the following:

    `"mainEntityOfPage": "Canonical URL of current page"`

Is it because the top-level type is `TVSeries` and not `WebPage` or `CollectionPage`?

Comment: @BAM: You could do this. You would provide a URL value (which is one of the two expected values), while I’m providing a `CreativeWork` value (the other expected value), which allows me to state that the current page is an `ItemPage` (i.e., a page about a single item). -- By the way, I created the issue "[Adding 'character' property to 'PerformanceRole'?](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/2175)", as I think the vocabulary is lacking in this aspect -- might be relevant for your data if something gets added to the vocabulary.